# reading a file word by word

Tags: c++, file

I can read from a file 1 character at a time, but how do i make it go just one word at a time? So, read until there is a space and take that as a string.

This gets me the characters:

```
while (!fin.eof()){
  while (fin>> f ){
   F.push_back ( f );
  }
```

Comment: Check out this SO post regarding string tokenization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Comment: `fin.eof()` indicates past failure; it does not tell you whether no more input remains.

Answer (score 3):

If your `f` variable is of type `std::string` and `F` is `std::vector<std::string>`, then your code should do exactly what you want, leaving you with a list of "words" in the `F` vector. I put *words* in quotes because punctuation at the end of a word will be included in the input.

In other words, the `>>` operator automatically stops at whitespace (or eof) when the target variable type is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
std::string word;
while (fin >> word)
{
    F.push_back(word);
}
```